# is it okay to mix Canvas objects (rectTransform) with regular game objects (transform), if those game objects have nothing to do with UI?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, canvas, transform

I've ended up in a situation where I have a parent Canvas element for my game's battle system (to display health text, etc), and have a mixture of UI stuff and controllable game objects as it's children. So some of the objects have `transform`, and others have `rectTransform`.

Here's a small sample of my hierarchy:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/Aa4wovx.png]

- The Parent **BattleCanvas** is a canvas object (`rectTransform`)
- **BattleEnemyObject** and **BattlePlayerObject** are regular gameObjects (`transform`)
- **BattleObjects** (a container for all instantiated objects) uses `rectTransform`,
- But its child **SnakePlayer** is a regular gameObject (`transform`)

I'm beginning to realize how messy this is, but things seem to work fine so far. So my question is, is it okay to mix Canvas stuff (`rectTransform`) with regular game object stuff (`transform`), if those game objects have nothing to do with UI?

I guess I sort of have a lack of understanding of the difference between `transform` and `rectTransform`. Any advice here is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is absolutely ok. `RectTransform` inherits from `Transform`. So all RectTransforms have all the functionality of a normal transform.

Many people change the canvases the render mode to `World Space` and then treat the `RectTransform` as a normal transform to space it in the world. There are some interesting effects like the one below that requires `RectTransform` to be used as a transform.

[image]

You can have multiple canvases with multiple render modes for some very interesting effects.